# Reverse Breadth First traversal in C#

Tags: c#, graph, graph-algorithm

Anyone has a ready implementation of the Reverse Breadth First traversal algorithm in C#?

By Reverse Breadth First traversal , I mean instead of searching a tree starting from a common node, I want to search the tree from the bottom and gradually converged to a common node.

Let's see the below figure, this is the output of a Breadth First traversal :
[image]

In my reverse breadth first traversal , `9`,`10`,`11` and `12` will be the first few nodes found ( the order of them are not important as they are all first order). `5`, `6`, `7` and `8` are the second few nodes found, and so on. `1` would be the last node found.

Any ideas or pointers?

Edit: Change "Breadth First Search" to "Breadth First traversal" to clarify the question

Comment: How do you find all leaves without traversing the entire tree?

Comment: Not without knowing more about the problem.  It's normally possible to start with one node and fan out, as in breadth-first search, depth-first search, iterative deepening, etc.  How are we supposed to know a priori that 9, 10, 11, and 12 are three hops from 1?

Comment: What did you use to make that image?

Comment: @David, in my problem the `9`,`10`,`11` and `12` are inputs. In other words, I already know that there are the "leaves"

Comment: FYI if this is a homework question please tag as homework.

Comment: @nifle, all the `9`, `10`,`11` and `12` are inputs

Comment: Huh, how can the leafs be the only thing you have? A tree is not uniquely determined by the leafs, so you MUST also be given a tree, otherwise the problem makes no sense.

Comment: @IVlad:  The tree can be implicit.  The starting nodes have to be explicit.

Comment: If this isn't a homework question why have you decided specifically on needing the use of reverse breadth first as your solution as opposed to stating the whole problem? Not that R-BFS isn't the correct solution but on SO it's hard to answer question like theses without knowing the actual context of the problem. When all you have is a hammer everything looks like a nail.

Comment: @IVlad: If every node has a pointer to its parent and you have the leaves, then you know the entire tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run a normal BFS from `rootNode` and let `depth[i] = linked list of nodes with depth i`. So for your example you'll have:

`depth[1] = {1}, depth[2] = {2, 3, 4} etc.`. You can build this with a simple BFS search. Then print all the nodes in `depth[maxDepth]`, then those in `depth[maxDepth - 1]` etc.

The depth of a node `i` is equal to the depth of its father node + 1. The depth of the root node can be considered 1 or 0.

Answer (score 21):

Use a combination of a stack and queue.

Do the 'normal' BFS using the queue (which I presume you know to do already), and keep pushing nodes on the stack as you encounter them.

Once done with the BFS, the stack will contain the reverse BFS order.